# File create time doesn't change even after it is deleted

Tags: python-3.8

I am using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time, pandas as pd, os, pickle
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,200))
fn = r'C:\z1.p'
pickle.dump(df, open(fn, 'wb'))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(fn).st_ctime)) 
os.remove(fn)
time.sleep(5)
pickle.dump(df, open(fn, 'wb'))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(fn).st_ctime))
```

But I get the same create time from both print statements as:

```
2022-03-16 08:43:30.885011
2022-03-16 08:43:30.885011
```

How do I make sure that new time gets printed for second print statement?

Answer (score 4):

This is a Windows feature, called "file system tunnelling".

[**The apocryphal history of file system tunnelling**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923)

> One of the file system features you may find yourself surprised by is
> tunneling, wherein the creation timestamp and short/long names of a
> file are taken from a file that existed in the directory previously.
> In other words, if you delete some file “File with long name.txt” and
> then create a new file with the same name, that new file will have the
> same short name and the same creation time as the original file. You
> can read this KB article for details on what operations are sensitive
> to tunnelling.
>
> Why does tunneling exist at all?
>
> When you use a program to edit an existing file, then save it, you
> expect the original creation timestamp to be preserved, since you’re
> editing a file, not creating a new one. But internally, many programs
> save a file by performing a combination of save, delete, and rename
> operations (such as the ones listed in the linked article), and
> without tunneling, the creation time of the file would seem to change
> even though from the end user’s point of view, no file got created.
>
> ...

See this archived copy of [Windows NT Contains File System Tunneling Capabilities](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/172190):

> When a name is removed from a directory (rename or delete), its
> short/long name pair and creation time are saved in a cache, keyed by
> the name that was removed. When a name is added to a directory (rename
> or create), the cache is searched to see if there is information to
> restore. The cache is effective per instance of a directory. If a
> directory is deleted, the cache for it is removed.
>
> These paired operations can cause tunneling on "name."
>
> - delete(name)/create(name)
> - delete(name)/rename(source, name)
> - rename(name, newname)/create(name)
> - rename(name, newname)/rename(source, name)
>
> The idea is to mimic the behavior MS-DOS programs expect when they use
> the safe save method. They copy the modified data to a temporary file,
> delete the original and rename the temporary to the original. This
> should seem to be the original file when complete. Windows performs
> tunneling on both FAT and NTFS file systems to ensure long/short file
> names are retained when 16-bit applications perform this safe save
> operation.

One Windows function related to file tunneling is [`FltGetTunneledName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltgettunneledname):

> The `FltGetTunneledName` routine retrieves the tunneled name for a file, given the normalized name returned for the file by a previous call to [FltGetFileNameInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltgetfilenameinformation), [FltGetFileNameInformationUnsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltgetfilenameinformationunsafe), or [FltGetDestinationFileNameInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltgetdestinationfilenameinformation).
>
> ...

[To disable tunnelling](http://www.tweakscene.com/viewtopic.php?t=7263):

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate here:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
3. On the Edit menu, point to New and then click `DWORD Value`
4. Type `MaximumTunnelEntries` and then press Enter
5. On the Edit menu, click Modify
6. Type `0` and then click OK
7. Restart your computer
8. Done